# Desktop application help framework

Tags: java, documentation, desktop-application

Consider the requirements for embedding help in a Java desktop application (or applet):

- Single source for content (such as [AsciiDoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/)) to generate high quality PDF manuals<sup>1</sup>
- Hooks for context-sensitive help
- Robust, simple, and well documented API (under an hour to learn)
- Small footprint (a sub-100K Java archive)<sup>2</sup>
- Integrate as a docked MDI-style window, or a separate window
- Free open source software

Google says:

- [JavaHelp](https://javahelp.dev.java.net/)
- [Java Programming Help](http://www.java2s.com/Product/Java/Programming/Help.htm)
- [Help Authoring Tools](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javahelp/industry.html)

Which of these, or any others, would you recommend?

<sup>1</sup>Storing the content in AsciiDoc format would be ideal, so long as conversion is trivial.
<sup>2</sup>Up to 500kb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at DocBook - last time I looked it could generate PDF, HTML and JavaHelp from files written in  DocBook XML .

A crash course is available at: http://opensource.bureau-cornavin.com/crash-course/

Comment: Am wondering more about the Java APIs -- is JavaHelp, for example, a suitable tool to use? I've taken a peek at DocBook before; thanks for the reminder.

Comment: JavaHelp is the tool Sun provides for help.  I have not heard of any other package to do so (except for the help in Eclipse, which probably is way over your head).

Answer (score -1):

Definitely Asciidoc, or its more recent cousin AsciiDoctor.

Comment: Based on what? Give a bit more information that would help the OP